# 403 error when submitting multiple paragraphs

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, ckeditor

I have a problem with a comment box input.

Everything works very well when only one paragraph is sent, but when multiple

tags are added, i recieve a 403 error. This doesn't happen on the localhost, only on the live website. The textarea is a rich-text editor using CKeditor. I use the same setup on another page where it does work. Can you please help me?

This is the form:

```
<div id="comment-form" class="container">
    <h3>Laat je mening horen!</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="blog-item.php?blogID='.$blogID.'">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="auteur" class="form-control" value="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="container col-sm-10">
                 <textarea rows="8" class="form-control" placeholder="Schrijf hier je commentaar" name="commbox" id="commbox"></textarea>
             </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Verstuur</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this is the php that processes the input:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST["commbox"])){
        echo '<p class="alert alert-danger">Je kan geen leeg comment versturen</p>';
    } else {
        $commbox = htmlspecialchars($_POST['commbox']);
        $auteur = $_SESSION['username'];
        $addCommStmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blogcomments (blogID, comment, auteur) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $addCommStmt->bind_param('sss', $blogID, $commbox, $auteur);
        $addCommStmt->execute();
        $addCommStmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the problem is with blog-item.php?blogID='.$blogID. try to save blogID in input type hidden field.

Comment: @saty: i don't think the $blogID is the problem, because it works when only one <p> tag is used and the $blogID is set to $_GET['blogID']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably not related to your code.Its more likely about mod_security on your server.In order to test Change the entire  text that you were trying to submit and if it went OK, You need to ask your host support to white list some of mod_security rolls.